# How is git able to check out the `main` branch after cloning despite it not being the remote's `HEAD`?

Tags: git

When cloning the same repo on two different machines, the result is different,

- On the first machine, all is good: `clone` finishes without warnings, the `main` branch is checked out, and the workspace contains the files from the latest commit on `main`.
- On the second machine, the clone operation finishes with a warning: `remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.`. The `main` branch is checked out, but the workspace is empty and the local `main` branch has no commits.

I logged into the remote server to inspect the bare git repo's config,

- `cat HEAD` --> `ref: refs/heads/master`
- `ls refs/heads/` --> `main`

Indeed, HEAD is pointing to the non-existent `master` branch.

Out of the multitude of settings available for git, which would cause the first machine to successfully pick up the `main` branch? The git configs on both machines as per `git config --list`, are identical,

```
user.name=Name
user.email=email@example.com
core.editor=code -n -w
core.excludesfile=~/.config/git/ignore
init.defaultbranch=main
push.default=current
```

yet the versions of git are different,

- The first machine (that successfully checks out `main`) is running `git version 2.42.0`
- The second machine (which fails) is `git version 2.34.1` (default on current Ubuntu LTS)

Are there any significant behavioral differences b/w these two versions?

Comment: Is `git config --list` identical on both machines? (There could be differences in `--global` or `--system` config) I was searching for a change in the git code-base between the two versions that would suggest that git now automatically guesses that "main" is the new name of a missing "master" branch (since that's a very common name change these days). I haven't found anything along these lines though. That's why I guess maybe it's a difference in configuration after all.

Comment: Thanks @Jay, updated with `git config --list` output

Comment: Perhaps try cloning with the standalone 2.42.0 and see if it works?